# How to serve gzipped assets from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip

I am currently serving all of my static assets from Amazon S3.  I would like to begin using gzipped components. I have gzipped and confirmed that Amazon is setting the correct headers.  However, the styles are not loading.

I am new to gzipping components, so possibly I am missing something?  I can't find too much information about this with Amazon S3.

Comment: Have you tried opening your browser's developer console and checking for errors accessing those resources?

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: Note: the above error is caused when you are serving a gzipped file from S3 without setting the proper content-encoding (see below).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For future reference to anyone else with this problem:

Gzip your components. Then remove the .gz extension leaving only the .css  or .js extension. Upload the files to your bucket.

From your S3 dashboard, pull up the properties for the file that you just uploaded. Under the 'Metadata' header enter this information:

```
'content-type'      :  'text/css' or 'text/javascript'
'content-encoding'  :  'gzip'
```

These value options are not available by default (wtf) so you must manually type them.

Comment: Absolutely marvelous solution. Thanks @Benjamin

Comment: 'content-encoding' was the missing key for me! S3 automatically assigned the 'content-type'. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I also found a solution how to do it using CLI, very useful when working with multiple files:

```
aws s3api put-object \ 
  --bucket YOUR_BUCKET \ 
  --key REMOTE_FILE.json \ 
  --content-encoding gzip \
  --content-type application/json \ 
  --body LOCAL_FILE.json.gz
```

Notes:

- Set `content-type` approppriately to what you're uploading
- The file name on the server doesn't need to have the `.gz` extension