# Amazon S3 gzipped files getting incorrect metadata and causing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

My static files are being served from Amazon S3. I am using circleci for my CI/CD to deploy my files. The files are getting added to the s3 bucket as expected, but when I go to the static website link I see a blank page with the console error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

Through some sleuthing (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080824/how-to-serve-gzipped-assets-from-amazon-s3/56782209) as one example) I found that the issue was in the metadata. The js files get added with a content type of `application/javascript` instead of `text/js`. When I manually go into my bucket and click on the individual files, go to Properties and then Metadata, and remove the existing content type and add the line `Content-Type` with a value of `text/js` for all the js `gz` files, the website starts displaying as it should. The only file that isn't a js file that's getting added is the `index.html` and that one gets the correct metadata (`text/html`).

I was super excited that it worked when I switched the content type, thinking I solved the issue. However, when I redeployed the app, the same incorrect metadata was added again. I found one solution to this, which was to add the `content-type` tag with a value of `text/js` during the deploy. This did work to get the correct content type associated with the `js.gz` files, BUT the index.html file is also being deployed. Since the index.html file also got the `text/js` file, we got the error "This site can't be reached".

Does anyone have any ideas for solutions? I am working on finding a way to dynamically choose one content type or the other, but I am wondering if there's a better solution. The app is being distributed through CloudFront.

Thank you for any help!

This is the end of my circleci config.yml where the deploy is happening:

```
      - run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y python-dev
      - run: sudo curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
      - run: sudo python get-pip.py
      - run: sudo pip install awscli --upgrade
      - run: aws --version
      - run: aws s3 ls
      - run: yarn run deploy
```

The line `yarn run deploy` runs this:

```
yarn build && aws s3 sync dist/ s3://[bucket] --delete --content-encoding gzip
```

The updated line that added in `content-type`:

```
yarn build && aws s3 sync dist/ s3://[bucket] --delete --content-encoding gzip --content-type text/js
```

**Update:**

I thought I found a solution by adding tags to include or exclude files by the extension, as should below.

```
"deploy-html": "yarn build && aws s3 sync dist/ s3://[bucket name] --exclude *.html --include *.gz --delete --content-encoding gzip --content-type text/js",
"deploy-js": "yarn build && aws s3 sync dist/ s3://[bucket name] --exclude *.js --include *.html --content-encoding gzip --content-type text/html",
"deploy": "yarn build && yarn run deploy-html && yarn run deploy-js"
```

However, that makes them unavailable in general so it results in the error:

```
Unknown options: server.js,webpack.common.js,webpack.dev.js,webpack.prod.js
```

Comment: You know, you have messed the order of the content types with the commands in the updated version? `deploy-js` operates on html and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by adding everything and then updating the metadata.

`package.json` scripts:

```
"deploy": "aws s3 sync dist/ s3://dallas-website --delete --content-type text/js --content-encoding gzip",
"update-metadata": "aws s3api copy-object --bucket dallas-website --content-type text/html --copy-source dallas-website/index.html --key index.html --metadata-directive REPLACE"
```

`config.yml` steps:

```
- run: yarn run build
- run: yarn run deploy
- run: yarn run update-metadata
```